# Django forms not adding textbox & not sending what user looked up

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

So the django file is not showing the form and at first, I got angry at that so I just used HTML code to create a form but I realized that when I submit it on the form it does not send it to where I want it to send. I was just wondering if you could help. I think the problem with the file is between the relationship between util.py file and the index.html file but I can't see it for some reason.
Thank you!!

util.py file

```
 class Form(forms.Form):
    searched = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
        
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            searched = form.cleaned_data['searched']
            return searched
        else:
            form = Form
            return render(request, "wiki/index.html", {
                "form" : form
        
                })
```

wiki.urls.py - main urls file

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("encyclopedia.urls")),
    path('wiki/', include("encyclopedia.wurls"))
```

]

encyclopedia.urls file

```
   from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

views.py file

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from . import util


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries(),
        "lookUp": util.get_name(request)
    })


def title(request, name):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/titlePage.html", {
         "entries": util.list_entries(),
         "name": name,
         "entry": util.get_entry(name)
        })
```

index.html file

```
    {% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block formsearch %}
<form action="/wiki/{{lookUp}}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ lookUp }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
       
        <li>   <a href= "/wiki/{{entry}}" > {{ entry }} </a> </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take away this from util.py:

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            searched = form.cleaned_data['searched']
            return searched
        else:
            form = Form
            return render(request, "wiki/index.html", {
                "form" : form
        
                })
```

and instead add this to views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            searched = form.cleaned_data['searched']
            return searched
        else:
            form = Form
        return render(request, "wiki/index.html", {
            "form" : form
            })
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries(),
        "lookUp": util.get_name(request)
    })
```